Total ground state energy calculation of an electron-ion system using plane wave basis sets
Recently I have begun working on a project which involves constructing a "simple" density functional theory (DFT) code using a plane wave basis set in Python. My first step has been to try and replicate total energy calculations for simple molecules, i.e. $H_2$, using numerical results obtained from Hartree-Fock (HF) calculations (using PyQInt). After I have done this, I can actually begin doing the real 'DFT' and construct solutions from a trial solution and include things such as the exchange-correlation energy etc. I am doing this as follows:

Find orbitals and energies for $H_2$ using HF calculations.
Using the orbitals from the previous step, construct the wave function $\psi(\vec{r})$ and electron density $n(\vec{r})$ in real space for some finite-sized, periodic, unit cell.
Fourier transform the wave function and electron density to get fourier coefficients $\tilde{\psi}(\vec{G})$ and $\tilde{n}(\vec{G})$.
Using expressions derived in literature, find the total energy $E = E_{nn} + E_{en} + E_{ee} + E_{kin} $, where the following terms are the nuclear-nuclear repulsion energy, electron-nuclear attraction energy, electron-electron repulsion energy, and the kinetic electron energy, respectively.

I have successfully calculated $E_{kin}$ and this result perfectly matches the result obtained by HF. For the other terms, however, the process is not so simple. First of all, the individual terms will not match the result obtained by HF, so verification of the individual terms is difficult. Secondly, the total energy will be slightly different, since with plane waves I am modelling a periodic system where as the HF calculation does not. To mitigate this effect, I am trying to compute these values with a box size much larger than the size of the $H_2$ molecule.
The $E_{nn}$ term I believe I am calculating properly using an Ewald summation. I am satisfied with this part as I have found a proper description of the derivation of this summation in different sources in literature (Understanding Molecular Simulation ch. 12.1, Domain-averaged Fermi holes: A self-interaction correction perspective A.2). However, this term is where some of my confusion begins. In the derivation of this Ewald summation, we suppose that a fictitious charge distribution exists between ionic charges that holds a Gaussian shape with some with $\alpha$. In the final expressions of the Ewald summation energy, this parameter $\alpha$ still exists, thus, implying, that your nuclear-nuclear repulsion energy is dependent on your choice of $\alpha$. Should this be the case?
I also have issues with the $E_{en}$ and $E_{ee}$ terms. As an example let us take the representation of the first term in real space:
$E_{en} = \int_\Omega \sum_{\vec{R}, j} n(\vec{r}) V(\vec{r} - \vec{R} - \vec{t}_j) d^3\vec{r} $
where $V$ is an ionic potential arising due to ion $j$ at position $\vec{t}_j$ and $\vec{R}$ is some Bravais lattice vector. $\Omega$ is the volume of the unit cell. Clearly, the energy involves summing over an infinite number of unit cells. This summation will converge, but slowly. Hence this is why I believe a lot of literature casts this energy into a form using reciprocal space. In literature (A plane-wave pseudopotential description of charged clusters) this is given in the following form:
$E_{en}' = \Omega \sum_{j,\vec{G} \neq 0} \tilde{n}(\vec{G}) \tilde{V}(\vec{G}) e^{i \vec{G} \cdot \vec{t}_j} $
Herein the $\vec{G} = 0$ vector is omitted as this term diverges. This term is also omitted for the momentum space representations of the other energies and literature shows that these terms cancel out. A similar expression can be found for the $E_{ee}$ term.
When calculating these energies, my professor explicitly back transforms the electron density and nuclear potential back into real space and then integrates over the unit cell. When he sums up the individual terms he obtains a total electron-electron repulsion and nuclear-electron attraction energy that almost exactly equal the result obtained from HF. However, I believe this step to be faulty. Firstly, by back transforming into real space and integrating over the unit cell, you are no longer taking periodic images into account. I believe the figure he obtains is only close to the HF value because we are using a very large box size (16 angstrom in x,y,z), so neighbouring $H_2$ molecules do not really interact anyway. By shrinking the box size I believe, for instance, that the electron-electron repulsion energy should increase, but with his code, it does not. Thus, I have the following questions:

Does back transforming the Fourier transformed nuclear (or electronic) potential into real space implicitly take into account the images? I.e. is my professor correct to do this and then only integrate over 1 unit cell?
From the literature I have seen I am missing step by step derivations on how to get to momentum space representations of these energies like I have shown above (in the little literature I can even find tackling this). I have tried deriving these myself but I am not confident in some of the steps I take and cannot justify whether or not moving these integrals from real space into momentum space is even justified. I also have issues with obtaining the correct $\Omega$ prefactor. Are there any resources this community can recommend me to find detailed derivations of these expressions?


If you don't get an answer here, consider to ask this on Matter Modeling SE.

It is not clear what you mean by doing the integral in real space over the unit cell; if it were done naïvely, then since you know that the result in Fourier space diverges, so it must also diverge in real space. The fact that it does not, likely means that your professor had already guaranteed that it does not, i.e. the correct adjustments had already been incorporated. That is why the literature needed you to understand why and how the zeroing of the $\vec G=\vec 0$ term is physically motivated and computationally performed. Things will make sense.

@naturallyInconsistent Thanks for the reply. By doing the integral in real space over the unit cell, I mean, by using the real space representations of the electron density and potentials, rather than the fourier components. So for calculation of Een, I mean to use the first equation I put in my post. You are correct that my professor already made an adjustment for the zero vector. My problem is more so with taking periodic images into account in the integration, not so much that I have an issue with this zero vector.

I'm trying to tell you that these two things are related. The zero vector sets up whether the periodic images causes explosion to infinity or not.

Not sure whether this helps in your understanding, but the derivation from the real-space expression to the expression using the plane-wave basis set is as follows.
Starting from the real-space definition
$$\Delta E_{e-e} = \int_{\Omega} \phi(\vec{r}) n(\vec{r}) d\vec{r}$$
where $\phi(\vec{r})$ is the Hartree potential as generated by a periodic charge distribution and $n(\vec{r})$ is the electron density. The electron density can be represented by a linear expansion in plane waves
$$n(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Omega}} \sum_{\vec{G}} c_{\vec{G}} \exp \left(i \vec{G} \cdot \vec{r} \right)$$
from which the Hartree potential can be calculated by means of the Poisson equation, yielding
$$\phi(\vec{r}) = \frac{4 \pi}{\sqrt{\Omega}} \sum_{G,\vec{G}\neq \vec{0}} \frac{c_{\vec{G}}}{|\vec{G}|^{2}} \exp \left(i \vec{G} \cdot \vec{r} \right)$$
where the $\vec{G}=\vec{0}$ term is ignored as this is a divergent term. Inserting these two expression into the first equation yields
$$\Delta E_{e-e} = \frac{4 \pi}{\Omega} \int_{\Omega} \sum_{G} \sum_{G\prime} \frac{c_{\vec{G}}c_{\vec{G}\prime}}{|\vec{G}\prime|^{2}} \exp \left(i \vec{G} \cdot \vec{r} \right) \exp \left(i \vec{G}\prime \cdot \vec{r} \right) d\vec{r}$$
which by virtue of the orthonormality relationship of the plane wave basis set can be condensed to
$$\Delta E_{e-e} = 4 \pi \sum_{\vec{G},\vec{G}\neq \vec{0}}\frac{c_{\vec{G}}^{2}}{|\vec{G}|^{2}}$$
showing how the phase-space representation can be derived from the real-space representation.
